# d3.geo: Path vs. Projection

Tags: json, path, d3.js, projection, geo

Currently, I am trying to learn how to use the d3.js API for geospatial mapping, but I am having trouble understanding how each part of the visualization works.  What is the difference between a path and a projection?

My current understanding is that the `d3.geo.path` is the coordinates I would use to create the shape I desire, and the projection is more along the lines of a layer I project onto my svg object.  However, I am confused as to what it means to have a default projection (which in the case of `d3.geo.path` is `albersUSA`.

Furthering on this question, do I need my own `json` files for `d3.json` in order to create the shapes I so desire?  So in the case of the United States map, would I need to find all the coordinates online and store them in a `json` file before I can create a proper `path` object?

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *projection* takes world coordinates (for example something like 20 degrees north, 5 degrees south) and converts them to map coordinates (for example 200 pixels to the right, 10 pixels down). A *path* takes these map coordinates and connects them such that you get a line (or series of lines). The projection is a conversion function, whereas the path takes care of the actual drawing. The coordinates are given by data that you pass to these functions.

There are examples on the D3 website for drawing specific "shapes", i.e. countries or world maps. You can use the JSON in these examples for your own purposes. If you want to show specific points or shapes that you can't find data for elsewhere, you'll have to provide your own JSON.

Comment: This helped clear up my understanding a lot better.  However, still wondering: what does it mean when the default projection is albersUsa?  Does that just mean that if I insert certain data, it will display as part of the US map?  And that the USA projection will show up?

Comment: This is only the name of the projection. It's just a function that transforms coordinates, it doesn't make your data part of the USA.

Comment: Oh, so it transforms any coordinates I put into it assuming that I'm using a US mapping?